# how to scrumble the word if i click a button

Tags: java, android, android-studio, button

How can I make a button that scrambles the letter every time I click it? When I try to make another button and then click it, it will scramble the letter. Then, when I got another word, when I clicked again on the scramble button, it was back to the first word I answered. (I'm just new. I'm sorry for my code).

```
 public static String wordJumble(String word )
{
    Random random = new Random();
    char wordArray[] = word.toCharArray();
    for(int i=0; i< wordArray.length; i++ )
    {
        int j = random.nextInt(wordArray.length);
        char temp = wordArray[i];
        wordArray[i] = wordArray[j];
        wordArray[j] = temp;
    }
    if(wordArray.toString().equals(word)){
        wordJumble(word);
    }
    return new String(wordArray);
}


@Override
protected void onResume() {
    super.onResume();
    final String [] str=quesWord.toArray(new String[quesWord.size()]);
    attemptsLeft.setText("Attempts left: "+chances);
    points.setText("Score: "+score);        
    jumbleWord.setText(wordJumble(str[0]));
    b.setOnClickListener(new OnClickListener() {
        int j=0;
        int len=str.length;
        @Override
        public void onClick(View v) {
            try{
                if(answerText.getText().toString().trim().equalsIgnoreCase(str[j])){
                    score++;
                    if(score==len){
                        dbHandler.addScore2("JL",score);
                        countDownTimer.cancel();

                        adb.setTitle("You Won!");
                        adb.setMessage("Score: "+score);
                        adb.setPositiveButton("Okay", new DialogInterface.OnClickListener() {

                            @Override
                            public void onClick(DialogInterface dialog, int which) {
                                finish();
                            }
                        });
                        adb.show();
                    }
                    j++;
                    points.setText("Score: "+score);
                    jumbleWord.setText((wordJumble(str[j])));
                }
```

> My shuffle Button

```
  shuffle.setOnClickListener(new View.OnClickListener() {
        int j=0;
        @Override
        public void onClick(View v) {
            j++;
            jumbleWord.setText((wordJumble(str[j])));
        }
});
```

Comment: what is the current output and what exactly is the problem you have?

Comment: When I click the shuffle button it went to another other set of word, then when I type the correct answer it say it's wrong.

Comment: isn't it because you increment `j` and `setText` only after that in the `onClick` method?

Comment: Can you help me. What can I do to fix it? I'm not really familiar in this.

Comment: what is `j` variable in the `onClick` method representing and why are you incrementing it?